# Sharing file descriptors between a parent and child after the child performs an exec call (UNIX/C)

Tags: unix, exec, fork, parent-child, pipe

I have an assignment in my OS class.  I am supposed to write three programs, one program reads from a file and writes to a pipe, one program reads from a pipe and writes to a file, and the third program is the parent which creates the pipe and does two forks in order to spawn the child processes, which immediately do exec() calls.  What I'm currently doing to make use of the pipe, is to pass the file descriptor in the exec() call as part of argv[], it works but it seems like the wrong solution.

What I want to know is if there is a better way to do this.  It seems awkward to be passing file descriptors through arguments.

Comment: Have code snippets been removed from this question?

Comment: This question should be closed: the answer is based apparently on some code that isn't available anymore.

Answer (score 3):

Child process after fork inherits parent's opened file descriptors. See `man 2 fork`.

Ok. My first advice for you is to compile with flags `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` to get all warnings. Now my changes in your code:

```
/*removed char pipe_readend[12];*/
char * arg[2] = {"test2", NULL}; /*first argument of program should be always it's name*/
char message[3] = {'h', 'i', '\0'}; /*c-string should be always terminated by '\0'*/
/*...*/
 case 0:
        /* child actions */
            close(pfd[1]); /* close write end */
            close(STDIN_FILENO); /*close standard input descriptor*/
            dup(pfd[0]); /*now standard input will be pfd[0]*/
            execve("test2", arg, NULL); /* start new process */
            break;
```

and test2.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (void){
    char msg[3];
    read(STDIN_FILENO, msg, 3); /*read from standard input*/
    printf("test2: %s\n", msg);
    return 0;
}
```

So to sum up: after forking you're closing standard input descriptor and duplicates pfd[0], which will become new standard input. Then call execve(), which uses pfd[0] as it's standard input. See more in `man 2` of functions `fork, execve, pipe`.

Comment: That doesn't really help. After the exec call I don't have any idea what the file descriptors are. Say the pipe uses fd 3 and 4, after the fork and before the exec call, I have those file descriptors in  variable pfd[0] and pfd[1], but after the exec call, I don't know those values anymore. I get that the file descriptors are inherited, and that I could blindly use the values 3 and 4 in read()/write() calls after the exec() calls and that they'd still work, but that seems like bad practice. Is there no better way to handle this issue than what I'm doing? Passing the file descriptors in argv[]?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/iwzFWSNU - That's a stripped down version of what I'm doing with just the parent and the child.  Passing the file descriptor in the argument.  It works fine, it just doesn't seem like common practice.